# Jquery trigger('click') close open select

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, triggers

I have a slider with autoplay option. It uses a trigger to the next button to show the next element. But if I have a select opened on my page, it closes, because this trigger click! How to solve this problem?

```
         slideshow  = setInterval(function(){
      $pxs_next.trigger('click');
     },o.auto);
```

Here you can see the trigger.

Comment: please, provide a jsfiddle which replicates your issue. Have you try using `$pxs_next.triggerHandler('click');` instead?

Comment: $pxs_next.triggerHandler('click'); That does the trick :) Thank you very much! Please add it as an answer and I will accept it!

Comment: You'd have better to call function directly if you are using a referenced function as click handler. If not, you should change your code to do it. See @RobSedgwick's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H i, you are losing the 'focus' of the `select` input.

Instead of using the 'trigger' to call the function, how about calling the function directly.

Imaging you have :

```
function dosomething() {
  console.log("I did something");
 }

 $pxs_next.on("click", function() {
    dosomething();
});
```

Instead of -

```
  slideshow  = setInterval(function(){
     $pxs_next.trigger('click');
   },o.auto);
```

Go directly to the function -

```
       slideshow  = setInterval(function(){
          dosomething();
       },o.auto);
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You can call click event after checking whether that element is opened or not in your set interval.
You can do this by adding and removing class from that element on open and close of that element.